# http invoke method for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, apache-nifi, elastic-stack

I have to convert this to an http invoke method to use in Nifi to index data into elasticsearch. any help is appreciated.

my elastcisearch url: http://localhost:9200/elastcsearch

POST /doc1/_update_by_query

```json
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "state_num": 4
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx.\_source.documents.add(params.text)",
    "params": {
      "text": {
        "number": "1",
        "docs_content": "this text goes here"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try the following method**

1. Create an Invoke HTTP processor in NiFi.
2. Set the HTTP Method property to POST.
3. Set the Remote URL property to http://localhost:9200/doc1/_update_by_query.
4. Set the Content-Type property to `application/json`.
5. In the body of the request, include the JSON payload of the original request:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "state_num": 4
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.documents.add(params.text)",
    "params": {
      "text": {
        "number": "1",
        "docs_content": "this text goes here"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

6. Run the NiFi flow, and the data should be indexed into Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created a parameter called 'body' with {"query"...} and passed with url http://localhost:9200/doc1/_update_by_query/${body}, it is throwing error.

Comment: can you share the error

Comment: UTC ERROR
java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x0a at 1 in body value :{ "query": { "term": { "state_num": 4 } }, "script": { "inline": "ctx._source.documents.add(params.text)", "params": { "text": { "number": "1", "docs_content": "this text goes here" } } } }